# Указание относительного пути в Java

Tags: java, javafx

Хочу загрузить картинку на форму в JavaFX - приложении. Сейчас делаю это следующим образом:

```
ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView("file:/hourglass.jpg");
```

Проблема в том, что так картинка берется прямо из корня диска D. Мне же надо задать путь относительно моей Java-программы. Конструкция, типа:

```
ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView("/img/ilovedogs.jpg");
```

не работает. Пишет вот что:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid
>   URL or resource not found

Как правильно все настроить и где создавать папку img ?

Comment: `img/ilovedogs.jpg` или `./img/ilovedogs.jpg`или всё тоже самое с добавлением `file:` спереди `file:./img/ilovedogs.jpg`

Comment: Спасибо! Оказывается надо было поставить точку вначале. Из всех вышеперечисленных работает конструкция ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView("file:./img/ilovedogs.jpg");

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте такой способ:

```
private static final File ROOT = codeSourceDir(Main.class);

private static File codeSourceDir(Class<?> clazz) {
    try {
        URI uri = clazz.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI();
        File jarOrDir = new File(uri);
        return jarOrDir.isDirectory() ? jarOrDir : jarOrDir.getParentFile();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new UnhandledException(e);
    }
}
```